# How to apply an asynchronous function into each item of a reduce operation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

*Googled* a ton of different sources, tried to figure it out for 2 days in a row, but nothing worked as expected until now. I'm a *bit* desperate and looking for other mind's ideas!

I'm trying to apply an asynchronous function I've written (that works with both promises and callbacks depending on the situation) inside a *reduce* function since I'm looking for the *reduced* value of the objects concatenated after each one is parsed, but I'm not succeeding on this feat yet.

**The function I want to apply in each object(article) of the big array of articles** looks like **this sample:**

```
renderEngine(
{'author': article.author, 'location': article.location},
'template.xml',
(err, parsedContent) => {
    if (err)
        callback(err, null)
    else
        callback(null, parsedContent)
})
```

How can one use a function like this with *reduce*?

Comment: Given that you don't need accumulator in the function you're applying, it's much easier (and faster!) to `Promise.map`, then `reduce` results. If you _really_ need it, Bluebird has `Promise.reduce`.

Comment: Do you want to call `renderEngine` *serially*, that is, one call after the last one is finished, rather than in parallel?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes!!! Forgot to mention that.

Comment: @Amadan actually I need an accumulator, because in the end of the reduce execution I need a string containing the result of the previously processed objects.

Comment: At the end of execution (i.e. as the final result), or during execution? Can you show a pseudocode (pretending the function is synchronous) of what you're doing? Because if "at the end of execution", there is no difference from my solution, except mine is fast (can be parallel). (You said the end result is concatenation of processed objects, which does not sound like needing accu). If you need the results of (i-1)th step in order to calculate the i-th step, you have the legitimate use of reduce (and can use Bluebird's implementation, or just take a look at their source to see how they do it).

Comment: @Amadan during the execution! It is like:
Apply a parsing function over each object of the array and concatenate the result of each iteration;
Take the **big** string and send it over the web;
Well, I did not write a pseudo-code because I'm doing a crazy amount of stuff and that is not important for the matter.

Comment: Man... Every time you try to explain it, I hear the same thing. Even @CertainPerformance's fine implementation that you approve of seems to do the same: invoke `getRender` on each object _separately_, and simply concatenate the independently obtained results. tl;dr: CertainPerformace's code is equivalent to `parsedArticles = await Promise.all(articles.map({ author, location } => getRender({ author, location })))` In order to show that this is not it, you need to show how the next step's result is influenced by the previous steps, not how the end result is.

Comment: @Amadan My `reduce` function `await`s the resolution of the `Promise` from the previous iteration before calling the `getRender` appropriate for the current iteration. See the comment inside the live code snippet. In other words, `reduce`ing like this sends out the requests in serial, not in parallel. Though, it's true, `Promise.all` *would* make more sense unless there's a real need for serial execution...

Comment: @CertainPerformance: I am aware yours is serial while mine is parallel. That is the point I am trying to make - that this is not a problem that needs a `reduce`. It makes it slower than my code, while returning identical results (since accumulator (`articlesSoFar` / `parsedArticles`) is not involved in the operation (`getRender`)). Am I wrong?

Comment: Oh, OK. Yes, `Promise.all` does *usually* make more sense,. OP explicitly said he wanted serial rather than parallel requests, but I don't know if that's for a good reason like rate-limiting or due to not knowing that `Promise.all` resolves with values corresponding to the the order of the array that's passed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea of using `reduce` with Promises is for each iteration to `await` the resolution of the accumulator, where the accumulator is the `Promise` that resolves once the previous iteration finishes. Here's a live snippet:

```js
const requests = [1, 1, 1];
const resolveAfterSeconds = function(sec) {
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, sec * 1000))
}

const doBatch = async function() {
  const results = await requests.reduce(async (listP, seconds) => {
    /*
    the reducer function isn't actually running sequentially itself;
    the functions all *start* synchronously immediately,
    but each awaits the resolve of the previous iteration before proceeding
    */
    const list = await listP;
    await resolveAfterSeconds(seconds);
    console.log(`returning ${JSON.stringify(listP)}`);
    // since this is in an async function, this gets automatically converted to a promise:
    return list.concat([seconds]);
  }, []);
  console.log(`done, results ${JSON.stringify(results)}`);
}
doBatch();
```

For your code, it would probably be useful to first transform the `renderEngine` call into a function that returns a `Promise`, and then it's pretty straightforward to call that function on each iteration:

```
const getRender = renderArg => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  renderEngine(renderArg, (err, parsedContent) => {
    if (err) return reject(err);
    resolve(parsedContent);
});

const parseArticles = articles => articles.reduce(async (articlesSoFarP, { author, location }) => {
  const articlesSoFar = await articlesSoFarP;
  const renderedArticle = await getRender({ author, location });
  return [...articlesSoFar, renderedArticle];
}, []);
```

But, it would probably be a lot clearer to read the code if you used a `for` loop instead:

```
const parseArticles = async (articles) => {
  const parsedArticles = [];
  for (const { author, location } of articles) {
    const renderedArticle = await getRender({ author, location });
    parsedArticles.push(renderedArticle);
  }
  return parsedArticles;
};
```

Comment: Really good comment, @CertainPerformance! Since my function already supports promises and _can_ return a resolve() or reject() if no callback is given, the _getRender_ part could be a bit refactored? Or making another promise _will_ help later in the code?

Comment: Sure, if `renderEngine` already returns a `Promise` if there's no callback, then just call it plain without the callback and without the `getRender` helper function

Comment: I'll try this when I get my PC later, and will come back here to tell you my results! Thanks a lot for now, @CertainPerformance!

Comment: I'm reading this and thinking about it, I'm aware that I should just pass the `array` to the function and let it work over it, but how could I print the result later? How could I use like `console.log`, just using `.then(results=>console.log(results))` or another fancier way?

Comment: That's exactly how you could do it, you can `forEach` over the array of results if you want to do something with each individual parsed article

Comment: It worked that way with `forEach`, but could I replace `const parsedArticles = [];` line with `let parsedArticles = ''` and `parsedArticles.push(renderedArticle);` with something like `parsedArticles += renderedArticle`? I tried to concatenate all `renderedArticle`s to then return a big string instead of an array, and it did not work like I wanted.

Comment: I suppose you could, but it would probably be better in terms of code organization to first get an array of the plain responses, and then transform the array later as needed, after everything else is done. It's good for functions to do *one thing* only, when possible